# Null JSON GET ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have two controller methods. I am passing two parameters from the 1st method to the 2nd. The values inserted to database are correct and not NULL. However when there are displayed back on the webpage in the return Json line, they come out as null and im not sure as to why? Here are the controller methods:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public void CalculateAndSaveToDB(BMICalculation CalculateModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CalculateModel.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            CalculateModel.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
            CalculateModel.BMICalc = CalculateModel.CalculateMyBMI(CalculateModel.Weight, CalculateModel.Height);
            CalculateModel.BMIMeaning = CalculateModel.BMIInfo(CalculateModel.BMICalc);
            db.BMICalculations.Add(CalculateModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        CalculateAndSaveToDB(CalculateModel.BMICalc.ToString(), CalculateModel.BMIMeaning.ToString());
    }



    public JsonResult CalculateAndSaveToDB(string o, string t)
    {
        var data = new
        {
            CalculatedBMI = o,
            CalculatedBMIMeaning = t
        };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Update

BMICalculationsModel:

```
 public partial class BMICalculation
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> BMICalc { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Height { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public int BMICalculationID { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public string BMIMeaning { get; set; }

    public double CalculateMyBMI(double KG, double Height)
    {
        return KG / (Height * Height);
    }

    public string BMIInfo(double? BMI)
    {
        string BMIInfo = "";

        if (BMI <= 18.5)
        {
            BMIInfo = "Underweight";

        }
        else if (BMI > 18.5 && BMI < 25)
        {
            BMIInfo = "Average";
        }

        else if (BMI > 25)
        {
            BMIInfo = "Overweight";
        }

        return BMIInfo;
    }

}
```

Comment: forgot return? `return CalculateAndSaveToDB(CalculateModel.BMICalc.ToString(), CalculateModel.BMIMeaning.ToString());`

Comment: what data type do i return? Its void at moment

Comment: BMICalc is double and BMIMeaning is string

Comment: I would suggest renaming the 2nd method as it doesn't do anything besides build the `JSON` and return it.  It is confusing to name it the same as the 1st method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your first method return `JsonResult` and not `void`. The second `CalculateAndSaveToDB` returns a JsonResult which never gets used.

I would definitely not call that second method `CalculateAndSaveToDB` as it doesn't save anything to the DB. Maybe `GenerateJsonCalc` would be more suitable or maybe no method at all:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CalculateAndSaveToDB(BMICalculation CalculateModel)
 {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          CalculateModel.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
          CalculateModel.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
          CalculateModel.BMICalc = CalculateModel.CalculateMyBMI(CalculateModel.Weight, CalculateModel.Height);
          CalculateModel.BMIMeaning = CalculateModel.BMIInfo(CalculateModel.BMICalc);
          db.BMICalculations.Add(CalculateModel);
          db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return CalculateAndSaveToDB(CalculateModel.BMICalc.ToString(), CalculateModel.BMIMeaning.ToString());
```

I would go for something like:

```
return Json(new
{
    CalculatedBMI = CalculateModel.BMICalc.ToString(),
    CalculatedBMIMeaning = CalculateModel.BMIMeaning.ToString()
 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Do I need both HttpPost and HttPGet in this case?

Comment: I've added [HttpGet] as well and it says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Should this be a `POST` or a `GET` method?

Comment: Both since its taking data from form as well i think

Comment: I think it has to be one of them. `POST` can return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Change your return type of your POST method and its last line to this:

```
public ActionResult CalculateAndSaveToDB(BMICalculation CalculateModel)
{
    //stuff

    return RedirectToAction("CalculateAndSaveToDB", new { o = CalculateModel.BMICalc.ToString(), t = CalculateModel.BMIMeaning.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Still null unfortunatley

Comment: Can you post the code for your BMICalculation class as well?

Comment: Are you calling these methods with Ajax?

Answer (score -1):

try return a dynamic object

```
public  dynamic  CalculateAndSaveToDB(BMICalculation CalculateModel)
{
   ...

   return  CalculateAndSaveToDB(CalculateModel.BMICalc.ToString(), CalculateModel.BMIMeaning.ToString());
}  

public dynamic CalculateAndSaveToDB(string o, string t)
{
    dynamic data = new new ExpandoObject();

    data.CalculatedBMI = o;
    data.CalculatedBMIMeaning = t;


    return  data ;
}
```